# Smooth subsurface problem

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

[image: subsurface]
I used a subsurface modifier, but the surface is still not smooth. I'm not sure what is wrong here. My setup is shown  above.

Comment: From screen it is hard to tell what the object should looks like. It seems like you have only one face and rest are only edges?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are in edit mode? 
If you want to affect object by modifier in edit mode press triangle icon.
For more informations about modifier see [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html).

[image]

What is this triangle icon? [Blender Manual sayes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#fig-modifiers-panel-layout):

**Show on cage (vertices-triangle icon) – Meshes only**

Depends on the previous setting, if enabled, the modified geometry can also be edited directly, instead of the original one.

**Warning**

While it shows edited items in their final, modified positions, you are still actually editing original data. This can lead to weird and unpredictable effects with some tools, and should be disabled whenever you need to perform complex or precise editing on the mesh.

Comment: @hjadsa: if the answer solved your issue, consider click on check-mark under vote arrows to sign this answer as "solved", so others can easily see it from a list of questions (don't worry you can uncheck it any time in a future).

Comment: what is this triangle for

Comment: The easiest way is try to press the button :) If it wasn't clear from the first sentence I edit it a bit and added description (What the icon is) from blender's manual. But if it is not your issue attach a blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?ref=be-community-add-2 It is hard to see/understand from your screen what is going on there). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also it may help to apply multiple subsurface modifiers to improve the surface quality if you are editing the surface afterwards. If you are sculpting, it may help to use dynamic topology to save memory. Smooth shading will look much better on a more complex surface.